# ¿Como detectar o escuchar cuando se reciben notificaciones de cualquier app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

Quisiera saber como es que se puede detectar cuando se recibe una notificación, tengo entendido que se puede hacer utilizando AccesibilityService, pero no logro que funcione, este el el código que tengo en mi servicio:

```
public class MyAccesibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

 @Override
 public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Evento de:" + evt.getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  public void onInterrupt() {

  }
}
```

También tengo declarado el servicio en el archivo manifest de la siguiente manera:

```
<service android:name=".MyAccesibilityService" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
            android:resource="@xml/accesibility" />
    </service>
```

Y este es el código del xml de meta-data

```
<accessibility-service
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme!

Comment: Te dejo este link https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm
fijate en los ficheros MyFirebase y en el manifest del proyecto y verás como se hace. Un saludo.

Comment: Si notificaciones te refieres a Push Notifications debes implementar FCM.

Comment: @Jorgesys me refiero detectar cada nueva notificación de todas las apps instaladas por ejemplo detectar cada que recibimos un mensaje por whatsapp, o una notificación de youtube. Es decir todas las notificaciones que aparecen en la barra de notificaciones